# Order by multiple properties with linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have list which I want to order by like this

```
public class Refund {
    public int RefundStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime SumbitTime { get; set; }
}
```

Order by `RefundStatus` first, then:

if `RefundStatus == 1` then by `SumbitTime` ascending,

if `RefundStatus != 1` then by `SumbitTime` descending.

How should i do by linq to sql?

UPDATE:
 I made changes followed Michal Turczyn .but log output display could not be translated

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression
>   'orderby [p].RefundStatus asc, ([p].SumbitTime.Ticks *
>   Convert(IIF(([p].RefundStatus == 1), 1, -1), Int64)) asc,
>   EF.Property(?[p]?, "Id") asc' could not be translated and will be
>   evaluated locally. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The
>   LINQ expression 'orderby [p].RefundStatus asc, ([p].SumbitTime.Ticks *
>   Convert(IIF(([p].RefundStatus == 1), 1, -1), Int64)) asc,
>   EF.Property(?[p]?, "Id") asc' could not be translated and will be
>   evaluated locally.

Comment: @vc74 sorry, I don't understand what your status mean. all the refunds in the collection have different refundstatus

Comment: @Z. Chen your question is not crystal clear to me, an example with sample data would help...

Comment: @Z.Chen Could you please provide sample input/ouput ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do that in following way:

```
List<Refund> refundList = new List<Refund>();
// populate your list
refundList = refundList
    // here you could also use:
    //.OrderBy(r => r.RefundStatus)
    // but I don't know if you want it this way
    .OrderBy(r => (r.RefundStatus == 1 ? 1 : -1))
    .ThenBy(r => r.SubmitTime.Ticks * (r.RefundStatus == 1 ? 1 : -1))
    .ToList();
```

The idea is that when you multiply by `-1` number of ticks in your `DateTime`, it will order it in descending order without having to split your collection to two parts.

Comment: It's a good idea but I'm not sure `Ticks` can be translated into SQL.

Comment: @vc74 This is handled by .NET and Linq2Sql framework internally. So you should not worry about it :)

Comment: Not all linq queries can be translated into SQL, especially those using .net features. But it may work, let's wait for the OP to try it...

Comment: it's a good idea,but it doesn't work.throw a exception  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  at  at lambda_method(Closure , AnonymousObject )
   at System.Linq.Internal.Lookup`2.CreateForJoinAsync(IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\Lookup.cs:line 301

Comment: @Z.Chen Check [NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I put Skip/Take after OrderBy-ThenBy. it run successfully .thanks~

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I tracked LINQ to SQL logs.@vc 74 may be correct .  logs output in my update

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are looking for if I understand your question properly.

```
var sorted = refundList.GroupBy(refund => refund.RefundStatus)
    .SelectMany(
        group => group.Key == 1 
        ? group.OrderBy(p => p.SumbitTime)
        : group.OrderByDescending(p => p.SumbitTime))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it doesn't work .throw a exception Argument types do not match

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following.

```
var sorted = list.GroupBy(refund => refund.RefundStatus)
                 .OrderBy(x=>x.Key)
                 .SelectMany(
                             group => group.Key == 1 ? 
                             group.OrderBy(p => p.SubmitTime)
                             : group.OrderByDescending(p => p.SubmitTime));
```

**Complete Example.**

```
        var random = new Random();
        var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
            .Select(x => 
                new Refund
                {
                    RefundStatus = random.Next(0,2),
                    SubmitTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(x)
                });
```

Where Refund is defined as

```
public class Refund
{
    public int RefundStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime SubmitTime { get; set; }
}
```

**Sample Output**

**Before Sorting

```
Refund = 0 - SubmitTime = 22-03-2019 14:22:16
Refund = 1 - SubmitTime = 22-03-2019 14:23:16
Refund = 0 - SubmitTime = 22-03-2019 14:24:16
Refund = 0 - SubmitTime = 22-03-2019 14:25:16
Refund = 0 - SubmitTime = 22-03-2019 14:26:16
Refund = 1 - SubmitTime = 22-03-2019 14:27:16
Refund = 0 - SubmitTime = 22-03-2019 14:28:16
Refund = 1 - SubmitTime = 22-03-2019 14:29:16
Refund = 0 - SubmitTime = 22-03-2019 14:30:16
Refund = 1 - SubmitTime = 22-03-2019 14:31:16
```

**After Sorting**

```
Refund = 0 - SubmitTime = 22-03-2019 14:31:16
Refund = 0 - SubmitTime = 22-03-2019 14:29:16
Refund = 0 - SubmitTime = 22-03-2019 14:28:16
Refund = 0 - SubmitTime = 22-03-2019 14:26:16
Refund = 0 - SubmitTime = 22-03-2019 14:23:16
Refund = 1 - SubmitTime = 22-03-2019 14:22:16
Refund = 1 - SubmitTime = 22-03-2019 14:24:16
Refund = 1 - SubmitTime = 22-03-2019 14:25:16
Refund = 1 - SubmitTime = 22-03-2019 14:27:16
Refund = 1 - SubmitTime = 22-03-2019 14:30:16
```

Comment: it worked on linq,but it can not  be translated into SQL